# If the total width of inline boxes are greater than line box's

Tags: html, css, inline

While reading the sitepoint reference on Inline Formatting, I came across this concept on their site:

> If the total width of the inline boxes is less than the width of the line box, the direction and text-align properties control how the boxes are distributed inside the line box.

But I made my own example where inline boxes are too long to fit into one line box and it breaks to the new line.

```
<p>lalala
    <em>some more lalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</em> 
    finish lalaa
</p>
```

.

```
p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Although the width of the inline boxes is greater than line box's (it's container), the `text-align` property is still being applied. So maybe I don't understand what they are trying to say with the quote above. I mean words inside `p` and `em` elements are inline boxes and the whole `p` tag creates line box? Please explain this to me.

Comment: What don't you understand exactly? When text covers the entire width (or exceeds it) then `text-align` becomes irrelevant because of overflow.

Comment: @Aziz That's the problem. My text covers the entire width and text-align is still being applied on the next line. Like the next line starts in the center, not left corner. Although the quote says otherwise. [link]http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/GqzAQB

Comment: `text-align` is irrelevant to the long line, the following lines will be aligned as defined, in your case to the center. Did you want this to behave differently?

Comment: @Aziz oh, I expanded my text in the em tag and now I see that it's not breaking to the new line like text in p tag does. Em text keeps going further and causes the scrollbar to show up. I thought text in p tag will behave as em tag coz I didn't understand the quote right. P is not inline box, right? And that quote is for inline elements only, like em tag. And em tag causes the line box to be created? Can you clearify me if I'm right? That whole inline box, anonymous box and line box stuff is very confusing for me. Em tag is line box in this case?

Comment: Yes `p` is a block tag and `em` is inline. However, when dealing with text that has no breaks (continuous characters), it will create scrollbar unless if it is forced to be broken with CSS to maintain the parent's width. This applies to all text regardless if their container is a block or inline.

Comment: @Aziz oh I see now. I tried to make characters seperated and even text in em tag honors the text align property. So i'm lost again. When then text align property becomes irrelevant? I know that quote says when line box runs out of space to place inline boxes. But how can I achieve such a thing? Who creates line box and how can I make my inline boxes to fill whole width of line box so text-align property would become irrelevant? Thanks for helping.

Comment: It is irrelevant in theory. Technically the `text-align` is still applied but when the text covers the entire line, you will not see the effect so in that sense it does not matter. If you want the `em` text to have a different alignment then you could make it as a block and apply whatever rules you want with CSS (even if the text does not cover entire width). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ptaa8ook/

Comment: @Aziz So it's only in theory. I thought like seriously something is going to happen... lol. And what do you mean by "but when the text covers the entire line, you will not see the effect" ? You mean that the line is going to take whole viewport or containing block and even without alignment it will look like centered because of the whole space it takes?

Comment: We can continue discussion on skype or gtalk.

Comment: Great, add me on skype: limpulis